# Copying high score to a readable variable to display in a label

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I need help with my high score system. So far I have the `receivedHighScore` variable I made (see below) being displayed on a label. This works and displays the value if I hard code it, but I can't get it to display the `retrievedHighScore`. Even if I try and make a global variable and use that when displaying it, I get `<TestGame.HighScore: 0x170224aa0>`.

If anyone could help me save the current high score `counter` into Score.HighScore or wherever it needs to go that would be awesome.

Currently I have two parts. HighScore.swift which includes:

```
import Foundation

class HighScore: NSObject {

var highScore: Int = 0

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder!) {
    aCoder.encodeInteger(highScore, forKey: "highScore")
}

init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    highScore = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("highScore")
}

override init() {
}
}

class SaveHighScore:NSObject {

var documentDirectories:NSArray = []
var documentDirectory:String = ""
var path:String = ""

func ArchiveHighScore(#highScore: HighScore) {
    documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    documentDirectory = documentDirectories.objectAtIndex(0) as String
    path = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("highScore.archive")

    if NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(highScore, toFile: path) {
        println("Success writing to file!")
    } else {
        println("Unable to write to file!")
    }
}

func RetrieveHighScore() -> NSObject {
    var dataToRetrieve = HighScore()
    documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    documentDirectory = documentDirectories.objectAtIndex(0) as String
    path = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("highScore.archive")
    if let dataToRetrieve2 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(path) as? HighScore {
        dataToRetrieve = dataToRetrieve2
    }
    return(dataToRetrieve)
}
}
```

and in my GameViewController I have this:

```
var Score = HighScore()
var receivedHighScore = HighScore()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    SaveHighScore().ArchiveHighScore(highScore: Score)
    var retrievedHighScore = SaveHighScore().RetrieveHighScore() as HighScore
    println(retrievedHighScore)

    receivedHighScore = SaveHighScore().RetrieveHighScore() as HighScore
}

func update() {

    labelCounter.text = String(counter++)
    var highScoreYes = counter
    Score.highScore = highScoreYes-1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get the highscore using:

```
var retrievedHighScore = SaveHighScore().RetrieveHighScore() as HighScore
```

retrivedHighScore is set to an instance of the HighScore object.

To get the highscore value you need to access the highScore property that retrivedHighScore has:

```
let currentHighScore: Int=retrivedHighScore.highScore
```